# How to avoid duplicate rows when joining across one of two routes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm writing a query in SQL server that can join across one of two routes. In the most common scenario, there will be a single link across one of the two routes. The problem is that if both of the two routes are valid, the results will contain duplicate rows. I'd like to understand if I can write the query to avoid the duplicate rows, without simply adding "distinct" to the front of it.

The query is intended to show the connection between users, stored in the party table, and the contracts they have access to.

If a user is assigned to a particular company, they can have access via the following route:

```
party (user) -> party_party_relationship -> party (company) 
-> contract (via company_party_id column)
```

However a user may also be assigned to a "work provider", which is similar to a company, and could also give them access to a contract, via a similar route:

```
party (user) -> party_party_relationship -> party (work provider)
-> contract (via work_provider_id column)
```

In the simple scenario, in which a user could only ever have a link via one  of the two routes, and in fact only has a single company, or single work provider, I can write a simple query where I left join to each route, like this:

```
select p.party_id as user_id,con.CONTRACT_ID
from contract con
left join party_party_rlship company_rlship on con.company_party_id =  
    company_rlship.child_party_id
    and company_rlship.nature = 'USER_COMPANY'
left join party_party_rlship work_provider_rlship on 
    con.WORK_PROVIDER_PARTY_ID = work_provider_rlship.CHILD_PARTY_ID
    and work_provider_rlship.NATURE='USER_CLIENT'
inner join party p on company_rlship.PARENT_PARTY_ID = p.party_id 
    or work_provider_rlship.PARENT_PARTY_ID = p.party_id
```

The problem is that in more complex scenarios, duplicate rows will be returned. As far as I can see, there are two different reasons dupes will be returned:

1. Could link twice to the same contract via both company and work provider.
2. Even if your companies link you to distinct contracts to your work providers, simply by having both, the second left join will cause a "multipler" effect. i.e. if a user links to three companies, and two work providers, the first left join will create three rows, then performing the second left join will join each of these to the two work provider rows, giving six rows.

Is there a way to structure this query to avoid the duplicates, without simply adding "distinct" to the front? I'm on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are struggling with here. Can you provide some sample data and desired output?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is an issue (other than your desired results). This should be expected in one to many relationships. If you want to select just 1 of those paths and have a specific method for choosing the order in which they would be prioritized, that's handled at the query level, not the structure level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised what I've got wrong here. Although there are two routes for the join, they are both on the same table, so this should be a single inner join with a condition that says either join via the company or the work provider, like this:

```
select distinct con.contract_id,ppr.parent_party_id as party_id 
from contract con
join party_party_rlship ppr on 
      ((con.company_party_id = ppr.child_party_id and ppr.nature = 'USER_COMPANY')
    or (con.work_provider_party_id = ppr.child_party_id 
        and ppr.NATURE = 'USER_CLIENT'))
```

In the worst case, each user will be linked twice, and these dupes can be removed with distinct. In my case, there are 3000 contracts, so the worst case scenario is that each user is linked to 6000. By contrast, with my previous two outer joins, I was creating a cross product of duplicates. Hence 3000 contracts could result in 9 million rows per user!

In addition, the final join to the party table is completely unnecessary. I only need the party id, which is in the party_party_relationship table.